# Artifacts on mesh from making cuts with knife tool?

Tags: artifacts, knife-tool

I'm a creator for the sims 4 and, for the purpose of creating for the game I use blender 2.70 (it's the one I have to use to be able to import to another external app to make new meshes).

Anyway, I've run into this issue and I don't know if there's a fix. While meshing a top, I had to cut parts of it to merge it with another part. To do so I used the knife tool to make new intersection vertices. The problem is, making cuts with the knife always leaves me with these hard edges/lines that are visible in solid mode in blender and can also be noticeable in the game. I tried messing around with some stuff in blender (such as sculpt mode, smoothing vertices in edit mode...) but nothing was able to get rid of this.
My question, therefore, is: Does anyone know how to fix this?

I included two images (1st is from blender view in solid mode and 2nd is from an external app - CAS Tools - in which you can see the issue).

Thank you so much for your time. If you have any idea on how to help I'd deeply appreciate it.

Edit 1: Added wireframe picture.

TL.DR.: Sims 4 mesh. Knife tools creates ugly hard edges on it that I don't know how to fix. Using blender 2.70.

[image: Knife tool artifacts]

[image: Knife tool artifacts 2]
[image: Wireframe view]

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it looks like the knife cuts are leaving tri's - blender uses quad-based rendering, and tri's and n-gons will often cause shading artifacts (especially on smooth shaded, rounded surfaces).

Comment: Can you post pictures of the wireframe?

Comment: Hey guys, I added a wireframe picture. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I think I see a vertex where 7 edges meet. I'm not sure this is what's causing the artifacts but might be it. It's something to avoid in topology, the ideal is to have only 4 (5 max) edges meeting at a single vertex.